# Reusable / dynamic / instance / symbol object (hack) in PowerPoint?

Tags: powerpoint

I've been searching for a while and can't imagine that there isn't a way ...

**Is it possible to create an object in PowerPoint, and create "dynamic copies" of that that will ALL change when you edit one?**

- Like what in Flash used to be called an "instance" (and object oriented programming OOP in general? not sure) .
- Like what in
  Illustrator is called a "symbol".
- In Sketchup a "component" has this behavior.
- In Revit a "group" sort of tries to do this in a terrible
  way.

Even a way to link an external (vector or raster image) file would be fine as a workaround, but not even that is possible in PowerPoint?!

Many thanks!//r

Comment: An object inserted on a slide master or layout will update on all slides when the master or layout shape is updated. You can also update multiple shapes by using VBA. Here's a free add-in that does that: http://www.pptools.com/free/FAQ00002-THOR-The-Hammer.htm

Answer (score 0):

I just make all the shapes of one type have the same name, e.g: `Menu_BTN` in my shape's selection pane.

And if I want to change the colour of those buttons spread over 100s of slides, I use the following macro:

```
Sub ChangeMenuBTNColour()
    Dim ppt As Presentation
    Set ppt = ActivePresentation
    Dim sld As Slide

For Each sld In ppt.Slides
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.Name = "Menu_BTN" Then
            shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(252, 225, 212)
        End If
    Next
Next sld
End Sub
```